# woocommerce brands custom fields

Tags: woocommerce, product, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working with woocommerce and i'm considering the brands extension. However, I want to add a lot more information to the brands than is shown possible. Does anyone here have experience with the extension and can I for example add custom fields to the brand page with Advanced Custom Fields?

Thanks to all who replies!

Answer (score 0):

ACF can be added to a taxonomy term edit page. Just select the location rule of ‘Taxonomy term’ and then select which taxonomy you wish for the field group to show on (product_brand).

Next, you will need to read this article to load the data into your template:

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/how-to-get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it to work with the brands plugin and ACf.